# Is it possible that a virtual machine knows that it is a virtual machine?

Tags: vmware, virtualization, qemu, kvm, xen

I'm asking because I think virtual machine should be unaware whether it is a virtual machine or a real machine.

But I think, there might be some clues from which the virtual machine knows that it is a virtual machine.

For example, to achieve high performance, there are some kinds of special hardware that support high performance virtualization, and from which the virtual machine could figure out it is a virtual machine.

Is it possible?

Comment: Only if we've experienced the Singularity, and the VM is sentient.

Answer (score 0):

<should be unaware whether it is a virtual machine or a real machine.

I think as long as virtual machine behaves like a normal machine, it should not matter, whether VM knows that it is VM or NOT.  :)

why do you THINK VM should be unaware?

With respect to qemu-kvm , if you are using hypervisor based drivers (say virtio-net) for your Ethernet interface, it means it is a Virtual machine. SO, Yes it is possible to know whether you are using a VM.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's possible.

In Xen, you can issue the "CPUID' instruction without input inside VM to get the information if the VM is running on Xen or bare metal. (This definitely work for PV VM, I guess it works for HVM as well)